# Tornado framework. TypeError: 'Future' object is not callable

Tags: python, asynchronous, frameworks, tornado, python-asyncio

I've started to learn Tornado framework sometime ago. I've faced the lack of documentation for unexperienced users and checked also asyncio module docs.
So the problem is, that I have some simple code in asyncio:

```
    import asyncio

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def compute(x, y):
        print("Compute %s + %s ..." % (x, y))
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        return x + y


    @asyncio.coroutine
    def print_sum(x, y):
        result = yield from compute(x, y)
        print("%s + %s = %s" % (x, y, result))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(print_sum(1, 2))
loop.close()
```

And then I've tried to make the same using Tornado framework:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen

@gen.coroutine
def compute(x, y):
   print("Compute %s + %s ..." % (x, y))
   yield gen.sleep(1.0)
   return (x+y)

@gen.coroutine
def print_sum(x, y):
   result = yield compute(x, y)
   print("%s + %s = %s" % (x, y, result))

IOLoop.instance().run_sync(print_sum(1,2))
```

But unfortunately Tornado code raise such an exception:

```
 Compute 1 + 2 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tornado_coroutine.py", line 19, in <module>
    IOLoop.instance().run_sync(print_sum(1, 2))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 421, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 209, in resul
t
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 402, in run
    result = func()
TypeError: 'Future' object is not callable
```

Maybe IOLoop tries to make an new "lap" after all coroutines have returned their values?

Answer (score 20):

`run_sync` takes a function (or other "callable") as argument. You are calling the function in-place and then giving the result as argument. You can create an anonymous function simply by using `lambda`:

```
IOLoop.instance().run_sync(lambda: print_sum(1,2))
```